# docker build fails with "permission denied" on `nginx -t`

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

I'm installing nginx on top of an `fpm-stretch` based php docker image, copy some configuration and then run `nginx -t` in the `Dockerfile`.
That one fails with `nginx: [emerg] open() "/tmp/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)`.

The configuration contains `pid /tmp/nginx.pid;`.

The `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM php:7.3.11-fpm-stretch
run apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx nginx-extras
COPY .system_conf/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY .system_conf/nginx/real-ip.conf /etc/nginx/real-ip.conf
COPY .system_conf/nginx/app.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
run touch /tmp/nginx.pid
run chown -R www-data:www-data /tmp/nginx.pid /etc/nginx /var/www /usr/local/etc/php-fpm*
run ls -la /tmp/nginx.pid
run whoami
run nginx -t
```

And the build output is:

```
Step 6/10 : run touch /tmp/nginx.pid
 ---> Running in b78b8c25da6e
Removing intermediate container b78b8c25da6e
 ---> 0ca504a62dcc
Step 7/10 : run chown -R www-data:www-data /tmp/nginx.pid /etc/nginx /var/www /usr/local/etc/php-fpm*
 ---> Running in 6d0e3e6e0085
Removing intermediate container 6d0e3e6e0085
 ---> 5801bebe1238
Step 8/10 : run ls -la /tmp/nginx.pid
 ---> Running in 3779596a2bf9
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 0 Aug  5 13:19 /tmp/nginx.pid
Removing intermediate container 3779596a2bf9
 ---> fa5fb9b67a43
Step 9/10 : run whoami
 ---> Running in 3c501d3ef8d0
root
Removing intermediate container 3c501d3ef8d0
 ---> f4c8d7c894a3
Step 10/10 : run nginx -t
 ---> Running in 91687a1ea4d2
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [emerg] open() "/tmp/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

And here comes the really weird thing:
This happens on my colleagues computer. On my computer, everything works fine as expected.
We are both running ubuntu (me 18.04, he 20.04) and the same docker versions (19.03).

Update 1:
I do `chmod 777 /tmp/nginx.pid` in the `Dockerfile` and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add a `user` directive to the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.3.11-fpm-stretch
run apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx nginx-extras
COPY .system_conf/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY .system_conf/nginx/real-ip.conf /etc/nginx/real-ip.conf
COPY .system_conf/nginx/app.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
run touch /tmp/nginx.pid
run chown -R www-data:www-data /tmp/nginx.pid /etc/nginx /var/www /usr/local /etc/php-fpm*
run ls -la /tmp/nginx.pid
user www-data
run whoami
run nginx -t
```

I still don't know why it would work on an ubuntu 18.04 but not on 20.04, though.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to grant permissions to the file `nginx.pid`.

Try this:

```
FROM php:7.3.11-fpm-stretch
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx nginx-extras
COPY .system_conf/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY .system_conf/nginx/real-ip.conf /etc/nginx/real-ip.conf
COPY .system_conf/nginx/app.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
RUN touch /tmp/nginx.pid
RUN chmod 755 /tmp/nginx.pid
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /tmp/nginx.pid /etc/nginx /var/www /usr/local/etc/php-fpm*
RUN ls -la /tmp/nginx.pid
RUN whoami
RUN nginx -t
```

Comment: The file has `644` which works fine on my machine. If that was actually the problem, it would not work anywhere, right?

Comment: I had the same issue and I've changed it to 755 and it worked. but I guess it solves the symptom and not the main problem. maybe @BMitch answer will solve the main issue.

Comment: I don't really see a reason to set the executable bit on a pid file, but I'll try.

Comment: That did not fix it

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check:

1. Pull the base image again, entirely possible they have done something to theirs: `docker pull php:7.3.11-fpm-stretch`
2. Check for SELinux being enabled on the host or docker engine (`docker info`).

Comment: No 1 did not help, and we both have `Security Options:  apparmor  seccomp   Profile: default`.